# Zooming into an image map causes hot spots to not line up

Tags: jquery, zooming, imagemap

I am running into a problem with an image map.  I have an image map with hot spots.  I'm also using imagepanner.js to perform simple zooming and panning of the image.  My issue is that after zooming into the image, the hot spots do not line up.  The hot spots are on the image map, but not in the appropriate places due to the zooming.  Is there a way to use JQuery or Javascript to re-calibrate these hotspots after a zoom-in or zoom-out happens?  I am using click events to trigger actions to retrieve information from the database, so the hot spots need to line up with the images after performing any zooming action.  Any ideas are greatly appreciated!